# magento 1 support from 2019 errors

Tags: magento-1.14

Good day

is Magento 1 still being supported at this moment?
Because I see no replies in the issues that are posted recently like 2019.
All the answers are two years most of them are no longer relevent like this

> Warning: is_readable() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given  in ...../web/lib/Varien/Io/File.php on line 535

I have been sitting with this error and doesn't seem like I am getting any answer in most magento platforms even here I haven't been answered.

Thanks

Comment: You are getting this error due to your PHP ver.

Comment: I am using php version 7.0 on production and also on local, so can you elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: ` protected function _checkSrcIsFile($src)
    {
        $result = false;
        if (is_string($src) && is_readable($src) && is_file($src)) {
            $result = true;
        }

        return $result;
    }`